# Latest News module not going away

Tags: joomla, module, joomla-module

So I tried to remove the latest news module. But it just kept on displaying on my home-page. How can i make it go away? I tried to clear cache, that did not work, also if I change the Menu Item Type of the home-page from featured articles to something else, the latest news module disappears then. How can I make it disappear without changing the Menu Item Type?

I tried to unpublished it but it wont go away, also there is no code for the module in the index.php.

[NerdyFuture](http://nerdyfuture.byethost24.com) link to my website the pictures next to the top news should be removed

Comment: please search alot before asking any question.

Comment: which version of joomla are you using?

Comment: @NimaNr Joomla! 3.3.6

Comment: Unfortunately, this question appears to be off-topic because it is only of use to the poster. Questions on Stack Exchange should be at least somewhere generic, so other people may learn from them.

Comment: (If you are still seeking an answer to this, please add in a screenshot of the problem, and the same for your more recent question. Links to external sites are not prohibited as such, but questions should not rely on them).

Answer (score 0):

go to `extensions> module manager>` unpublish your module. then go to your front-end view and use `CTRL+F5` for refreshing your site.

Comment: Thanks, but it's still there